# Link to view - Dynamic Data List Freemarker Template - Liferay

Tags: templates, view, liferay, freemarker, dynamic-data-list

I'm creating a freemarker template for a dynamic data list in Liferay.
Now, I would like to redirect to view entry / record on clicking the link in this data list.

Actually I hava a view button, which works fine. But I wonder how could I do this using link.
I tried to make `<a href="${portletActionURL}">` but this didn't work.

My code for the view button:

```
<td>
    <#assign controlPanelGroup = groupService.getGroup(portalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId(), "Control Panel")><#assign controlPanelPlid = layoutLocalService.getDefaultPlid(controlPanelGroup.getGroupId(), true)><#assign portletActionURL = portletURLFactory.create(request,"167",controlPanelPlid,"ACTION_PHASE")>
        ${portletActionURL.setParameter("recordId", "${cur_record.getRecordId()}")}
        ${portletActionURL.setParameter("struts_action", "/dynamic_data_lists/view_record")}
        ${portletActionURL.setParameter("redirect", "${themeDisplay.getPortalURL()}${themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()}")}

    <#if permissionChecker.hasPermission(scopeGroupId, "com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.model.DDLRecordSet", "${reserved_record_set_id}", "VIEW")>
    <form action="${portletActionURL}" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="view">
    </form>
    </#if>
</td>
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: I can't understand what you want... the entire row of the table should be a link?

Comment: If your button click is redirecting accurately, then this <a href="${portletActionURL}">VIEW</a> should do the trick. Note: Remove the form, just simply place this link.

Comment: @Parkash Kumar, Hi Parkash, THX for your reply! I tried to to  <a href="${portletActionURL}">VIEW</a> but this doesnt works.. If i klick this link, it open the control panel, but says ""dynamic data list temporaly not availible" ... Any ideas why?

Comment: A message with `temporaly not availible` nearly always indicates an exception that is logged in the log. This log would help to find the cause.

Comment: @Parkash Kumar, So no it works fine. But it open the "view" in the control Panel. In the Default Dynamic Data List ist opens the "view" inside the portlet.. Do you have an idea how i can do this too ?

Comment: You are passing it, controlPanelPlid, therefore, it would be opening control panel url.

Comment: @ParkashKumar, sorry i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: It means, that you might have issue with your URL.

Comment: @ParkashKumar, no it works, i had to change "action_phase" to "render_phase". But do you alsow have an idea, how i can open the "view" inside the Portlet and not in the control panel??

Comment: Change your URL creation to: PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, "167", themeDisplay.getPlid(), "RENDER_PHASE");

Comment: @ParkashKumar, if i insert this code it says: Expression PortletURLFactoryUtil is undefined on line 50, column 39 in 10154#10194#113071. Any Ideas why?

Comment: Change themeDisplay.getPlid() with $themeDisplay.getPlid()

Comment: @ParkashKumar, So i changed PortletURLFactoryUtil to PortletURLFactory, Now it doesn't throw an error, but if i press my "view link" it just relodes the page

Comment: http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/11/working-with-liferay-urls.html, You would require service for PortletURLFactoryUtil, then you can create proper url using it.

Comment: @ParkashKumar, so first of all: Thank you for you replies. Now i did what you told me and it throw this error: Expression $themeDisplay is undefined on line 50, column 80 in 10154#10194#113071.

Comment: @ParkashKumar, sorry but, how can i add this service?

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+to+Liferay+services+in+Velocity

Comment: @ParkashKumar, this is Velocity, i'm using freemarker :(

Comment: @ParkashKumar, No ideas?